# Why JSON.parse cant detect if argument is already in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json

As we know `JSON.parse` parses the stringified `JSON`, but if a variable is already `JSON` and you try to do `JSON.parse` on that it throws an error :

```
> a
[]
> a = JSON.parse(a)
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at repl:1:10
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
```

Why cant `JSON.parse` verify that argument is already a `JSON object` and do nothing in that case instead of throwing an error?

Comment: My be owner expected developers to be smart enough to use it....

Comment: I think one of the problems will be that `[function(){}]` will be returned from `JSON.parse` just like that, although it’s _invalid JSON_. You’d have to make a check for those cases… By the way, edge cases like `JSON.parse({toString: function(){return "[1, 2, 3]";}})` may not return the expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the ECMA docs on `JSON.parse`, it looks like the first thing the `parse` method does is stringify the first argument using `toString()`. You can check the docs themselves here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.2.

In other words, `JSON.parse([])` is equivalent to `JSON.parse([].toString())`, which is equivalent to `JSON.parse("")`. Looking at it this way, the error `unexpected end of input` actually makes much more sense. There's nothing to parse in an empty string.

Answering your question more directly, it would require some performance overhead for `JSON.parse` to infer and serialize a native javascript object into JSON (JSON isn't javascript). Furthermore, it would violate the single responsibility principle (SRP). It's the responsibility of `JSON.parse` to parse strings, not objects.

Answer (score 2):

**Why not use the passed object as a valid JSON**
If passed an object to `JSON.parse(obj)`, it is transformed to a string: equivalent to `obj.toString()` or `'' + obj`. It does not try to verify the passed object as a valid JSON.

**Why an error is generated**
The problem with `[]` empty array is that it transforms to an empty string: `''` and this is not a valid JSON.
In case of empty string isn't possible to return a `null` or `undefined`(because they have valid JSON strings: `JSON.parse('null')` or `JSON.parse('undefined')`) and throwing an error is an useful option.
Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) the exact JSON format.

**Equivalent working examples**
The following examples are working fine because the object transforms to a valid JSON string:

```
JSON.parse({toString: function() {return '{"a": 1}'}}); // prints an object {a: 1}
JSON.parse([1]); // prints a number 1
JSON.parse('""') // prints an empty string ""
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `JSON.parse`, not `JSON.tryParse`. If you really need to pass in some input and you don't know if it's stringified or not, you will need to develop your own methods for determining so. I'm glad it doesn't do this. It's current behavior is simple and correctly throws an error if I did something stupid so that I know to correct it.